# Checkbox location changes when workbook is opened in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am using Excel 2007 at home to develop a sheet for work that has data input using multiple checkboxes.  Each checkbox is in an empty cell.

When I open it at work with Excel 2010, all the checkboxes have changed position by a few pixels to the right.  Just enough to partially obscure the border of the adjourning cell.  Unfortunately, I don't have sufficient space to enlarge the cells.  I need to print the sheet after it's filled in.

Does anyone know if this is normal when saving on one version of Excel and opening on another?  Is there a workaround?

Comment: A VBA macro could run through all the checkboxes and align them to the left side of their TopLeftCell but that's not a very elegant solution.

Comment: What format are you saving it as?

Comment: The format was saved in .xlsx

Answer (score 0):

I would think this has to do with using different monitors as well as font-size and DPI settings on Windows.

I would start by making sure both of your computers have the same settings under Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Display:

[image]

To get to this screen, just type 'make text' in the Start Menu and it should be the first link to show up.

[image]